# how to limit amount of smb connections to remote host?

Tags: smb, tcpsocket

I'm trying to watch fs structure of remote host with Windows 7/XP SMB shares using libsmbclient library. The code something like that:

```
bool open(QList<DirType> &resList){
    SMBCFILE* dh = smbc_getFunctionOpendir(ctx)(ctx,rootpath.toLocal8Bit());
    if (dh==NULL) return false;
    smbc_dirent *res;

    bool isitZeroLevel = false;
    while (res=smbc_getFunctionReaddir(ctx)(ctx,dh)){

        if (res->smbc_type==SMBC_FILE_SHARE) isitZeroLevel=true;
        struct stat aboutres;
        smbc_getFunctionStat(ctx)(ctx,(rootpath+"/"+smb_name).toLocal8Bit(),
                                  &aboutres);

        DirType d(res->smbc_type,res->name,aboutres.st_mtim.tv_sec);
        resList.push_back(d);
    }
    smbc_getFunctionClosedir(ctx)(ctx,dh);

    if(isitZeroLevel){
        smbc_setOptionOneSharePerServer(ctx,1);
        close();
    }
    return true;

}
```

this code is recursively called for every directory on server, and on my Samba server works fine. But Windows reject connections on some point. I think that Windows has some limit for connection, and smbclient makes them too much. 
(running on linux-3.4.9 with samba-3.5.15)